# cómo agrupar y ordenar registros

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente duda tengo una tabla en mi base de datos tengo los registros de número de cuenta y año lo que quiero es puedo ordenar las cuentas y agruparlas por año, por ejemplo:

```
________________
cuenta | Año  |
100    | 2011 |
128    | 2006 |
130    | 2003 |
100    | 2012 |
100    | 2011 |
130    | 2004 |
```

y que el resultado quede así:

```
___________________
cuenta | año
100    | 2011
100    | 2011
100    | 2012
128    | 2006
130    | 2003
130    | 2004
```

Lo intenté con un :

```
GROUP BY año
ORDER BY cuenta
```

pero no me saca lo que quiero, agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta no necesita para nada `GROUP BY`, porque no estás "agrupando" tus resultados. Sólo necesitas el criterio correcto del `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT cuenta, año
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY cuenta, año;
```

Comment: Hola, pues no, no los agrupa por año, lo que hace es crear por rangos de años, es decir, tengo años repetidos para la cuenta 100, y lo que hace es poner primero cuenta 100 año 2011, 2012, y luego otra vez cuenta 100 año 2011, 2012

Comment: Entonces deberías haber puesto en tu data de ejemplo casos con años repetidos y el resultado que quieres. De todas formas, incluso con la edición que hiciste a la pregunta, esta consulta te entregará ese resultado, no entiendo bien cuál es el problema

Answer (score 1):

Para obetener lo que deseas debes incluir las dos columnas en al clausula GROUP BY seria algo similar:

```
SELECT cuenta, año ,sum(*) as 'cuenta' FROM nombre_tabla GROUP BY sum(*) ASC, año ASC ;
```

Te generara grupos diferentes de cuenta y año .

Answer (score 0):

Lo intentanteste con

order by año desc   u order by año asc

para ordenarlos en forma ascendente o descendente ?

otra opcion a lo que entiendo es que agruparas el total de cuentas que tuviste en un cierto año es decir

2010  3

donde 2010 es el año y tuviste 3 cuentas a lo largo de ese año, o lo estoy entendiendo mal ?

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta el ejemplo, creo que la consulta que necesitas sería:

```
SELECT cuenta, anio FROM table ORDER BY anio DESC, cuenta
```

En este caso no necesitas el GROUP BY ya que eso te combinaría (por decir de alguna manera) los registros.